# Snakeyaml 2.0 compatibility with Swagger and Jackson

Tags: security, jackson, dependencies, swagger, snakeyaml

Snakeyaml 1.33 has a vulnerability(CVE-2022-1471) which is mitigated in Snakeyaml 2.0.
Our systems use Swagger(2.0.9) and Jackson(2.14.1) which indirectly rely on Snakeyaml 1.33 and hence Snakeyaml got added into our dependency chain.
We want to force update to Snakeyaml 2.0 but want to check if Swagger and Jackson are compatible with 2.0

I verified the implementations and both Swagger and Jackson are not impacted by this vulnerability, so our systems are not impacted as of today. However, we want to upgrade the dependencies to avoid getting any potential security threats.
I verified the underlying implementations and learnt that Jackson 2.14 can be compatible with Snakeyaml 2.0 but I am very much unclear about Swagger 2.0.9's compatibility.

Kindly direct me to a resource if this is already answered.

Comment: jackson 2.14.2 has a fix that let's you use snakeyaml 2.0 - better still use jackson 2.14.3 (with further bug fixes). I think you may need to upgrade swagger to 2.2.9 - swagger 2.0.9 may not work Jackson 2.14.